# Metrics with unit volume form on a Riemannian surface

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

I struggle to come with an argument why any local metric on a Riemannian surface cannot be put into the form
$$
 g = \dfrac{d x^2}{F(x,y)} + F(x,y) d y^2.
$$
so that the metric is diagonal, and the volume form is unit: $\omega = dx \wedge dy$.

I am aware of the following results (and their proofs), but they do not seem helpful in this case

- on a Riemannian surface one can always locally write metric as conformally flat (see [isothermal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isothermal_coordinates) on Wikipedia)
- on a Riemannian surface one can always locally diagonalize the metric with the given function being one of the coordinates (see, e.g. Appendix C in [arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0408141](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0408141))

Comment: Since Gaussian curvature $K$ is the only local metric invariant, it seems worth trying to calculate $K$ for this $g$ to see if this particular form of the metric would lead to any particular restrictions on $K$, such as sign.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Thanks for advice! I will keep updated!

Comment: I think that by Cauchy-Kowalewska theorem one can always solve the resulting PDE of Gauussian curvature for any given value of $K$

Answer (score 0):

As @MikhailKatz pointed in the comments, the only local obstruction to introduction of a metric on a Riemannian surface is a Gaussian (or scalar) curvature. The latter is given by
$$
R = -F_{xx} + F^{-3} \left( F F_{yy} - 2 F^2_{y}\right)
$$
where lower indices stand for respective derivatives, for example, $F_{xx} = \partial_x^2 F(x,y)$.

If one treats the equation as an inhomogeneous PDE for $F$, then by Cauchy-Kowalewskaya theorem, for any **analytic** $R$ one can always supply boundary conditions such that the solution to the boundary problem exists.

P.S. This is a very sketchy proof I made to convince myself. Please point out if my application of C-K theorem was incomplete, or the result can be strengthened to smooth functions too.

Comment: It seems to me that the relation between the metric and the curvature function is not completely straightforward.  Certainly if curvature is constant, the metric can be recovered up to isometry.  Otherwise, there is some work involved.  There is work by Nirenberg on Weyl and Minkowski problems (the latter is the one relevant to your question).